# How can I add a name of place to google map using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How I can add a name of place to google map using javascript as shown in the image?

Any solutions for that?
Many thanks!
[image]

Comment: Thank @Samuel J Mathew

Comment: You can use the [Place Add](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place) of the Google Maps Places API Web Service. It is the one that you will use if you want to add new places in the Google Maps Database. When you add a place, the new place is available immediately in Nearby Searches initiated by your application. The new place also enters a moderation queue to be considered for Google Maps. A newly-added place does not appear in Text Search or in other applications, until it has been approved by the moderation process. For more information, just read the documentation guide

Comment: Unfortunately, [Place Add](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place) has been deprecated on June 30, 2017 and will stop working on June 30, 2018. So you cannot use this method anymore. For further details please refer to the corresponding [geo blog post](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2017/06/announcing-deprecation-of-place-add.html).